# Cloudflare Worker fetch to same domain endpoint does not execute

Tags: cloudflare, cloudflare-workers

I have a worker that’s under the `worker.example.co`. Within the worker, there’s a [fetch](https://developers.cloudflare.com/workers/runtime-apis/fetch/) request to `gql.example.co`. DNS for the domain is handled by Cloudflare. The worker is obviously hosted there, but the external endpoint is an A record pointing to an external API (i.e. `someapi.fly.dev`).

No matter what I do, that request never fires. Not fails; it just never happens. Using the original endpoint for the API (`someapi.fly.dev`) works just fine. And using that API as `gql.example.co` works just fine *outside* the Worker.

The problem is specifically within the Worker; making a request from the same domain endpoint. Is there something I need to do on Cloudflare to make this work or is it simply not possible?

---

Routing for the Worker: `worker.example.co/*`

[Repo with in question.](https://github.com/fourjuaneight/bookmarker/blob/main/src/hasura.ts#L92-L99)

---

**Update 2023:** While mostly anecdotal, I can confidently say that any `fetch` inside a Worker calling an endpoint whose DNS is also handled by the same Cloudflare account, will not work. I'm likely missing some sort of binding, but I could not find any concrete answer or documentation about any of this. For the time being, pointing to the IP address instead of the domain works just fine.

Comment: What do you mean by  it just never happens?

Comment: Can you clarify: You're saying a worker runs on worker.example.co, and it makes a fetch() request to gql.example.co. gql.example.co is configured to point to the same IP address as some service under fly.dev. When you fetch() from the worker, you never see the HTTP request arrive at the latter service. But when you curl gql.example.co from your desktop, it works? Is that right? Additional questions: Is gql.example.co set to proxy through couldflare, or is it set to DNS-only? What kind of HTTP response (e.g. status code, body text) is returned by the fetch() when it doesn't reach the server?

Comment: @KentonVarda That is precisely right. And it's **not** proxied; DNS-only. As for the response, that's the thing. When I log the request itself, it's always empty.

Comment: The request is empty? Or the response is empty? What's the status code on the response?

Comment: @KentonVarda The **request** is empty. No status code.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "the request is empty". I thought you said the request was never received by your server. Where are you seeing it empty? And what do you mean when you say the response has no status code? All HTTP responses have a status code, it's part of the protocol which cannot be skipped.

Comment: @KentonVarda As I stated in the original post, the request never fires. Logging the variable where the request is to be returned is empty (per Cloudflare Worker logs). There's no missing context here. Exactly what I'm saying is exactly what is happening.

Comment: Are you trying to directly log this variable request without await?
https://github.com/fourjuaneight/bookmarker/blob/main/src/hasura.ts#L92
Could you try logging with `const text = await request.text(); console.log(text)`?
Same with status.

Comment: @KshitijJoshi **With** await. Also added logs for the request and response as text, per your suggestion. The log stream from Cloudflare looks like this, just empty objects:
```json
{
  "logs": [
    {
      "message": [
        {}
      ],
      "level": "log",
      "timestamp": 1661879332495
    },
    {
      "message": [
        {}
      ],
      "level": "log",
      "timestamp": 1661879332495
    }
  ],
}
```

Comment: In my opinion, it seems to be an issue with the promise/async code. Your setup looks fine to me.  Is there a way for you to simplify the code and test the setup instead of testing the actual code? Or vice versa, maybe to confirm if your code works as expected, instead of calling to the Hasura endpoint, just fetch a `GET` call to google.com and see if you get back the response?

Comment: @KshitijJoshi I thought that too. So when I change that URL to the original fly.dev endpoint, request fires just fine.

Comment: @fourjuaneight I tried out your setup on a worker & some random DNS records on my domain and it seems to be working fine for me. So not sure how can I help more without knowing specific IPs and domains. Wish you all the best! :) Do post a note here if you manage to figure out the problem.

Comment: @KshitijJoshi yeah, it's a weird bug. Still debugging. I appreciate the help. I'll update the question if I find a solution.

Comment: Haven't gotten far, but some updates:
- Setupping up a variable for the request outside the try/catch and logging the variable on the catch does yield something: `null`
- Running `wrangler dev` locally works just fine. No errors.

Comment: Re: the 2023 update. I've found a similar issue when trying to call a service with DNS managed by Cloudflare. I found by switching the proxy status to DNS Only in the Cloudflare dashboard the issue is resolved.